# Databases - equivalent of ERD, UML and in relation data model

Tags: database, relational-database

I have got this question:

What is the equivalent of table in ERD, UML and in relation data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chen's ER model (and Chen-notation ERDs), data is represented as attributes of and relationships between entities.  This is an interpretation of relations in the relational model, which understands data as associations between domains of values/entities.  Relations (i.e. attributes and relationships) can be represented as tables, though tables and relations don't map 1-to-1 - certain rules and semantics must be applied to tables (such as eliminating merged cells, ensuring that every cell contains exactly one value, column values are from a single domain, no duplicate rows, and order of rows/columns aren't significant) to understand them as relations.

In non-Chen ERDs (the kind in products like Visual Paradigm and MySQL Workbench), tables are directly represented but called entities, and foreign keys constraints are called relationships.  This is reminiscent of the pre-relational network model.  UML class diagrams fall in this category when used for data modeling.